# wine-platform-5-staging & wine-platform-runtime not found by shell

Tags: zsh, path, snap

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 64-bit with zsh as my shell. I installed [wine-platform-runtime](https://snapcraft.io/leagueoflegends) and [wine-platform-5-staging](https://github.com/mmtrt/leagueoflegends/issues/134) as snaps. However, zsh doesn't recognize it's installed.

The following 3 commands don't work:

- `wine`
- `wine-platform-5-staging`
- `wine-platform-runtime`

I haven't tried switching to bash and testing the commands.

When I installed Wine from their website previously, it worked just right.
I need those packages specifically in order to run some software ([League of Legends](https://snapcraft.io/leagueoflegends))

I've had path issues with zsh before — could it be the reason?

Update: `which` doesn't work for any of them, either, yet they're still installed.

Update 2:
answer from the developer of the [leagueoflegends snap](https://snapcraft.io/leagueoflegends) on the [repository of the snap](https://github.com/mmtrt/leagueoflegends/issues/134) about the path - there are no launchers nor exec commands:

> This snap (`leagueoflegends`) uses wine-platform-5-staging & wine-platform-runtime snaps respectively are basically content snap which does not provides any launchers or exec commands but are mounted in this snap root path to expose there content to be used..

Still, why is my shell still unable to find them (as per update 1)?

I installed `leagueoflegends with` --devmode`.
Could it be somehow with the installation being restricted, per the [snap documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement)?

> Devmode
> A special mode for snap creators and developers. A devmode snap runs as a strictly confined snap with full access to system resources, and produces debug output to identify unspecified interfaces. Installation requires the --devmode command line argument. Devmode snaps cannot be released to the stable channel, do not appear in search results, and do not automatically refresh.

Comment: It's probably a path issue indeed. I think snap installs programs in nonstandard locations. I guess it adds them to the path in a way that only works with bash.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix this? I don't know much about wine so I don't know what file I should `source` in `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't run Kubuntu and don't use Snapcraft, but when I install `wine-stable` through Homebrew, it runs an installer which puts it in `/usr/local/bin/`, which is already in my path.

Try installing `wine` again and in the installer's output, take note of where the commands get installed. Then, check if that dir is in your `$path`, by doing `echo ${(F)path}` on the command line. (The `(F)` puts each item on a new line, for easier readability.) If the dir where the `wine` commands get installed are not in your `$path`, then you can add it like this (using `/usr/local/bin/` as an example value):

```bsh
typeset -U PATH path
path=( /usr/local/bin/ $path )
```

(`typeset -U` ensure you don't get duplicate entries.)

Comment: Did you install it via snap or via your regular package manager? Please do notice my 2nd update. I think it could be because of the snap installation restriction(s).

Comment: No idea, but good to see that you've got a conversation going with the developer of that snap. Hopefully, he can sort it out for you.